# How to vlookup a part of a cell

Tags: excel, vlookup

How do I VLOOKUP the Text "D123456" in a cell? So a letter D followed with 6 random numbers. matches with exact the same combination on the other sheet.

I want to match the code "D + 6randomNumbers" with the exact same code on an other sheet/selection..

```
Blabla S.E. - D1606070 - Bezwaar afwijzing vkv - BIP 29 sep 2016 - 8UJ2812
Blabla L.J. - D1606063 - HB terugvordering bijstand - BIP 16-8-2016 - 4MG0445
Blabla A.J  - D1706024 - Bezwaar afwijzing ambulante - BIP 5-4-2017 - 42JI4214
Blabla N.P. - D1606026 - Beroep afwijzing kaart - BOB 11-4-2016 - 4MW4861
Blabla J.R. - D1606073 - Bezwaar intrekking - BIP 28 oktober 2016 - 4IR5876
Blabla M.A. - D1706045 - Bezwaar visum kor - BIP 24 april 2017 - 4GJ9013
```

The code at the end should not be checked..

Layout:

[image]

**Edit 19 november 2017:**

I got a small problem here... What if we got this two strings at the **Test TV** sheet:

```
Blabla R.J. - D1706029 - Bezwaar wijziging bijstandsuitkering m.i.v. 1 maart 2017 - BIP 7-4-2017 
Blabla R.J. - D1706034 - VOVO hangende bezw wijziging bijstandsuitkering miv 1-3-2017 - BIP 7-4-2017 (smh D1706029)
```

And I only want an 1 if the D1706034 is a match on the other sheet... and don't want a 1 at the D1706029.. Because only this string is on the **Test Decla** sheet:

```
Blabla R.J. - D1706034 - VOVO hangende bezw wijziging bijstandsuitkering miv 1-3-2017 - BIP 7-4-2017 (smh D1706029)
```

Comment: Is Blabla S.E. - D1606070 - Bezwaar afwijzing vkv - BIP 29 sep 2016 - 8UJ2812 all in one cell? Just want to check.

Comment: Yes it's in one cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to return a 1 if found and a 0 if not found, use:

```
   =IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*"&MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+1,11)&"*",A:A,0)),0,1)
```

In your example you would put something like the following in cell O11 and drag down for as many rows as required,

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*"&MID(B11,FIND("-",B11,1)+1,11)&"*",'Test Decla'!A:A,0)),0,1)
```

B11 has the string to search.

The following extracts the pattern "D123456- " (where 123456 is 6 random numbers); assuming always after first "-" AND that the end number (if present, is not followed by " -".)

```
MID(B11,FIND("-",B11,1)+1,11
```

You would change this `'Test Decla'!A:A` to whichever the match column is in the other sheet.

NOTE: I have changed the pattern to encompass an additional 2 characters so only matches if found at start of string.

Example of data in sheet where formula is

[image: Formula in sheet]

Example of where trying to match against

[image: Search area in other sheet]

Comment: I'm struggling getting it right: (lol give me a moment to explain, I pressed enter exidently)

Comment: Can you post an image of your data? You replace A:A with the column your long strings are in e.g. Blabla S.E. - D1606070 - Bezwaar afwijzing vkv - BIP 29 sep 2016 - 8UJ2812. You replace C14 with the cell that has the value you want to find e.g. D1606070, you modify the range to return a value from by changing A:B to the appropriate column ranges. Would be easier if i knew what your data layout was like including which rows/columns are involved.

Comment: I will make a screenshot, moment!

Comment: I need to see the layout of your data. Can you update post with images of the data you are working with? So can see the columns/rows holding the data and the sheet names.

Comment: Also, do you understand how a vlookup works? You can't return column L for example from a lookup range of B:C with a return column of 2. It will be clearer if i can see your data but look carefully at how the vlookup works in relation to the image i have posted. It is looking to return the second column from A:B i.e. B. The substring to look for must be outside of the vlookup range in my example. In this case column C. In your example you might lookup a substring in column G against a range B:F seeking to return column number 5.

Comment: I've uploaded an image, thanks for your answers, really appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you actually just wanting if substring is found in other sheet return 1 otherwise return 0?

Comment: What are your random numbers looking for?

Comment: @QHarr: At your last comment: Yes!

Comment: Hello QHarr, I had a busy weekend BUT I just looked at it in the excelsheet AND it totally worked... Thank you very much for your solution wizard!

Comment: Hey QHarr, I edited my question: see text after edit. Do you have an solution for it?

Comment: Please see edited question. Based on assumption there is always " -"  after the pattern stated.